# on click change Document card color SPFX

Tags: css, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react, reactjs

I have developed a webpart where on hover i am changing the color of document card office fabric component and on click of document card i am showing grid ,but i am not able to change color of document card if i click ,it only changing in hover

below is my code

```
                            const cardStyles: IDocumentCardStyles  = {
                              root: [
                                {
                                  display: 'inline-block', marginRight: 20, borderRadius: 25,  marginBottom: 20,width: 90, 
                            backgroundColor:"#fbce07", outline:'none',borderStyle:'none',border:0,borderColor:'white',textAlign: "center" ,color:"white",
                            selectors: {
                              ':hover': {
                                backgroundColor:'#ff9933' ,outline:'none',borderColor:'white',borderRadius: 25

                              },

                              ':after': {
                                color: 'transparent',
                                content: '',
                                display: 'block',
                                height: '1px',
                                overflow: 'hidden',
                                visibility: 'hidden'
                              },

                              ':before': {
                                color: 'transparent',
                                content: '',
                                display: 'block',
                                height: '1px',
                                overflow: 'hidden',
                                visibility: 'hidden'
                              },

                            }
                                }
                              ]
                            };

                            const cardStyles1: IDocumentCardStyles  = {
                              root: [
                                {
                                  display: 'inline', marginRight: 20, borderRadius: 25,  marginBottom: 20,width: 90, 
                            backgroundColor:"#fbce07", outline:'none',borderWidth:0,borderStyle:'none',border:0,borderColor:'white',textAlign: "center" ,color:"white",
                            selectors: {
                              ':hover': {
                                backgroundColor:'#ff9933' ,outline:'none',borderColor:'white',borderRadius: 25

                              },
                              ':after': {
                                color: 'transparent',
                                content: '',
                                display: 'block',
                                height: '1px',
                                overflow: 'hidden',
                                visibility: 'hidden'
                              },

                              ':before': {
                                color: 'transparent',
                                content: '',
                                display: 'block',
                                height: '1px',
                                overflow: 'hidden',
                                visibility: 'hidden'
                              },

                            }
                                }
                              ]
                            };


                            ShowGrid(a)
                            { 
                              var reactHandler = this; 

                               if (usertype=='Yes')    
                                         {

                                      jquery.ajax({ 
                                        url: `${reactHandler.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Templates')/items?$select=Title,CurrentReportLink,HistoricalReportLink,DataGroupTemplate/Template&$expand=DataGroupTemplate&$filter=DataGroupTemplate/Template eq'${a}'`, 
                                        type: "GET", 
                                        headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'},
                                        success: function(resultData) {

                                        reactHandler.setState({ 

                                        items2: resultData.d.results 

                                        }); 

                                        }, 
                                        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                                        } 
                                        });  


                                    }



                                   else
                               {


                                      jquery.ajax({ 

                                        url: `${reactHandler.props.siteurl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Templates')/items?$select=Title,CurrentNonReportLink,HistoricalNonReportLink,DataGroupTemplate/Template&$expand=DataGroupTemplate&$filter=DataGroupTemplate/Template eq'${a}'`, 
                                        type: "GET", 
                                        headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'}, 
                                        success: function(resultData) {   

                                        reactHandler.setState({ 

                                        items3: resultData.d.results 

                                        }); 

                                        }, 
                                        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                                        } 
                                        });  



                                  }




                              } 

                              public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactGetitemsProps> {
                               return (   
                            {this.state.items.map((items,key)=>
                            {    
                              return(

                                <DocumentCard styles={cardStyles} onClick={() =>this.ShowGrid(items.Template)}>
                                <DocumentCardTitle   title={items.Template} />
                                <DocumentCardImage styles={cardStyles1}  height={100}imageFit={ImageFit.cover}  imageSrc={items.ImageLink ? items.ImageLink["Url"] : ''} />
                                </DocumentCard>

                                );
                                );
```

Comment: in `OnClick` function you can try getting the documentCard element by some selector and then try adding some CSS through code.

Comment: if i put '':active': {
    backgroundColor:'green' ,outline:'none',borderColor:'white',borderRadius: 25
   
  },
  '  it work on click but goes away suddenly

Comment: active will work only when you click on it or you press and hold left button of mouse after that will go away.

Comment: yes right it work only on hold and press

Comment: any other way to achieve this i am only stuck on this

Comment: As I said in my first comment, are you able to fetch te DocumentCard element in your Onclick function? If Yes, then you can add style to the element from your code(TS file... Not CSS or SCSS).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101150/change-color-of-selected-element-react worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using below code:

```
toggle(b)
{

  if (this.state.description === b) {
    this.setState({ description: null })
  } else {
    this.setState({ description: b })
  }

}

myColor(b)
{
  if (this.state.description === b) {
    return "#ff9933";
  }
  return "";

}
```

**Reference**: [Change color of selected element - React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101150/change-color-of-selected-element-react).